# Direct link (no redirect) to files in ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

Using `url_for()` on a file stored in active storage returns a url that leads to the application and then redirects to the actual location. Because of a [bug in firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1346749) with CORS, the redirect breaks my application.

Is there any way to get the direct link to the file with ActiveStorage?

Comment: I know you've fixed this using the solution that @jean posted, but have you tried setting up a CORS policy so that you can continue using `url_for` (or `polymorphic_url`). At least that way you will be able to keep the path to your assets hidden from public, which can have all sorts of benefits.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch CORS is set up properly but the old version of the CORS spec said don't follow redirects and firefox hasn't changed it yet.

Comment: that's strange because I'm seeing no CORS related problems with firefox at all. Perhaps they've quietly fixed it. Running the latest, on Ubuntu 18. Oh well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this

`record.active_storage_object.blob.service.url`

Found here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L213

Comment: yeah, that seems to be a more direct way of the method I found.

Comment: Your link returns a 404: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/blobs_controller.rb

Comment: Thanks, method and link has been fixed!

Answer (score 3):

I had to dig through the rails source to create this so I have no idea how recommended it is but this works for disk storage at least.

```
ActiveStorage::Current.host = "yourhostname"
attachment_blob = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_by(record_type: "YourModel", record_id: record.id).blob
direct_url = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.url(
    attachment_blob.key,
    expires_in: 20000,
    disposition: "attachment",
    filename: attachment_blob.filename,
    content_type: attachment_blob.content_type
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 7 `blob.service_url` doesn't work anymore, it's simply `url` now.

So: `record.active_storage_object.url`

Answer (score 0):

For me, `rails_blob_url(@blog.pdf)` (if you're trying to get the file stored as `@blog.pdf`) worked best.

Comment: This gives you the redirect url